# How the `dispatch_get_main_queue` works?

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(isFullfilMyCondition){

      //Do some complex thing

      return;
    }
});

//Another things
```

If I put the return statement inside the `dispatch_get_main_queue`, it will not `return` it will execute the `Another things`. But if I modify my code like this:

```
if(isFullfilMyCondition){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //Do some complex thing

    });
    return;
}

   //Another things
```

Then, the return statement execute, what's going on under the hood? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dispatch_async` does the block you give it asynchronously, as the name implies. That means that execution of the code outside the block continues to execute until completion first.

Also, the `return` is to return from the block, not the function.

Comment: Also, important to note that you can't return a value from an asynchronous dispatch and receive it at the call site.